# Manually compile QT project with g++

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, compilation, g++

I am currently working on a polymorphic engine that works for c++ projects. What i am doing is that i am

(1) generating assembly files from .cpp files

(2) generating object files from assembly files

(3) loading object files into an .exe

All this is done using the g++ compiler through the command line. Now, all this works fine for a regular win32 c++ console application project created in visual studio, but i also need to adapt my polymorph engine to be able to build QT projects (GUI) with the same method of approach listed above.

I am unable to find commands to replicate this for QT projects. Below is the commands i am currently using in order to manually compile a console application project built in Visual studio.

(1) g++ -S -masm=intel -o my_asm_output.s main.cpp 
// generate assembly from main.cpp file

(2) g++ -c -o my_obj_output.o assembly.s 
// generate object file from assembly.s

(3) g++ -o my_exe_output.exe my_obj_file.o 
// generate executable by loading object file into it

Thanks!

Comment: You need to invoke [moc](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/moc.html)

Comment: Alright, will look into it. Thanks!